# Getting module's name from model's name

Tags: php, yii, model, module

I need to know a module name for a particular model, if I know only model's name.

For example, I have:

- model `Branch`, stored in `protected/modules/office/models/branch.php` and
- model `BranchType` stored in `protected/modules/config/models/branchtype.php`.

I want to know the module name of `branch.php` from the class of `branchtype.php`.

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Yii does not provide any native method to determine the module name that model belongs to. You have to write your own algorithm to do this task.

I can suppose you two possible methods:

1. Store configuration for module's models in the module class.
2. Provide the name of your model using path aliases

**First method:**

MyModule.php:

```
class MyModule extends CWebModule
{
    public $branchType = 'someType';
}
```

Branch.php

```
class Branch extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function init() // Or somewhere else
    {
        $this->type = Yii::app()->getModule('my')->branchType;
    }
}
```

In configuration:

```
'modules' =>
    'my' => array(
        'branchType' => 'otherType',
    )
```

**Second method:**

In configuration:

```
'components' => array(
    'modelConfigurator' => array(
        'models' => array(
            'my.models.Branch' => array(
                'type' => 'someBranch'
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

You should write component ModelConfigurator that will store this configuration or maybe parse it in some way. Then you can do something like this:

BaseModel.php:

```
class BaseModel extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $modelAlias;

    public function init()
    {
        Yii::app()->modelConfigurator->configure($this, $this->modelAlias);
    }
}
```

Branch.php:

```
class Branch extends BaseModel
{
    public $modelAlias = 'my.models.Branch';

    // Other code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Yii::app()->controller->module->id.
```

Or inside a controller:

```
$this->module->id
```

Comment: That's only get the current model's module. But I want to get other module name.

Comment: As Thyu said, and this will throw an error on console apps (which don't even have a controller).

Answer (score 0):

in Yii2 try this:

```
echo Yii::$app->controller->module->id;
```

for more information see [Get the current controller name, action, module](https://devreadwrite.com/posts/yii-framework-2-get-the-current-controller-name-action-module)